# Search bar with core data

Tags: iphone, core-data, uisearchbar

I have added search bar in my tableview and I am having number of cities in table view from core data.I read some examples but didn't understand how to implement search bar with core data.Please give me some example or tutorial link..Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using an NSFetchedResultsController?

Comment: Yes I am using NSFetchedResultsController

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all make use of one of the UISearchBarDelegate methods like `searchBar:textDidChange:`.

I don't know how your search should be performed. This an example how to query for a text which should contain the searchText.

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(%@ contains[c] %@)", fieldName, searchText];
    [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
}
```

Comment: You'd like to search right? You enter to search a string. You enter the string in your searchbar. To react on entered text you have to use some of UISearchBar's delegate methods. Please read Apple's documentation on that. Can you flesh out a bit more how the search should work?

Comment: I have city names in alphabetic  order ..I want to search city name by letter like phone book contact search, and I am having City entity and name is attribute  in core data.

Comment: What's the exact field name of the a city's name?

Comment: "Name"  is the city's name attribute